estou desenvolvendo um site em php e my sql e e preciso de um sistema multiusuário
Preciso que cada usuário quando entre no sistema tenha suas próprias informações que guardou no banco de dados, como fazer isso? crio um banco de dados para cada usuário?

Considerando que esta pergunta já foi feita o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações.
